# .htaccess - Map files inside fake directory to actual directory using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

On the website, students will be given a link to log in that includes the school's name in the url. There are unlimited possibilities for the school name. What needs to happen I need to rewrite

```
example.com/schoolname/anyfilename
```

to the actual file

```
example.com/pages/anyfilename?school=schoolname
```

The school name could be anything.

Any advice on how to achieve this using a .htaccess file?

---

EDIT: I also need to have the subdirectories rewrite as well:

```
example.com/schoolname/directory/subdirectory/file
```

Maps to

```
example.com/pages/directory/subdirectory/file?school=schoolname
```

Comment: what is the schoolname is "pages"?

Comment: @amenadiel "pages" is the actual directory that it needs to be rewritten to. Every school name will be rewritten to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question regarding "pages" was meant to say that if you rewrite everything, you'll enter a redirection loop = Error 500. For starters, I'd suggest rewriting only when the uri doesn't point to an existing file or folder.

That being said, this is the .htaccess I would use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(.*)$ /pages/$2?school=$1 [L]
```

Edit: just to be on the safe side, I'd add one more RewriteCond just before the RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I had to remove the `[L]` from the end to get it to work without redirecting and it works great!

Comment: sorry about that, I stopped using apache long ago and I have nowhere to test these kind of answers quickly, but I'm glad to see you sorted it out.